# CSS - Background Image Stretch

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to get a similar background effect that's on this website:

[image]

By looking at it, the background of the website is black, but has a horizontally stretched background image that remains at the top of the page. When the page is scrolled down, the image stays at the top but blends into the background color.

I tried making an image like the one in the example and used `background-size:cover` but when I scroll down, the image stays static and just the contents scroll. If that makes any sense at all!!

By looking at the example, could somebody kindly explain what CSS is needed to achieve this? And also, what should the image size be (in PS), to allow it to stretch in larger browsers without losing quality?

I tried looking at the website's CSS file to see what was happening, but it's all on one line and confusing to work out.

I would add a link to the site to show how it scrolls, but apparently I'm not allowed, so a screenshot will have to do.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't link to your web site. Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @Diodeus: It's not my website. I don't understand how I can show the experts on SO any other way. I can put up a screen shot but it won't explain the scrolling part of the question. How do I get around that?

Comment: You should attempt to explain the question without the use of a link.

Comment: To ensure you do not use quality when stretched, I wuld recommend using a .png image.

Comment: @Diodeus: I have edited the question to abide by the rules you mentioned. If you down-voted, I would appreciate an up-vote if you're satisfied with the format of the question now it's been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that background uses the css:

```
background:#000000 url(<img>) no-repeat scroll center top;
```

Which sets a background colour AND image, places the image statically at the top, so that after scrolling down, the background colour is only visible.

To see this effect, using chrome, change the css to:

```
background:#00FF00 url(<img>) no-repeat scroll center top;
```

and you will see what is going on.